# How do you lift a binary function to monad transformers?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I know you can lift functions to monads with `liftM`, but I it doesn't seem to work with binary functions.

I tried to lift `(+)` but it didn't work

```
a = return 1 :: ExceptT String Maybe Int
b = return 2 :: ExceptT String Maybe Int
liftM (+) a b

• Couldn't match expected type ‘ExceptT String Maybe Int -> t’
                  with actual type ‘ExceptT String Maybe (Int -> Int)’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these:

```
liftM2 (+) a b
liftA2 (+) a b
(+) <$> a <*> b
```